# How can we show $\int_0^xu^{-\alpha}(t,r)u_r(t,r)\:{\rm d}r=\frac{u^{1-\alpha}(t,x)-u^{1-\alpha}(t,0)}{1-\alpha}$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, partial-differential-equations, parabolic-pde

Let $R,T>0$ and $u\in C([0,T)\times[0,R])C^{1,\:2}((0,T)\times[0,R])$ satisfy $$u_t=u_{xx}+u^p\;\;\;\text{in }(0,T)\times(-R,R)\tag1$$ for some $p>1$ and $$u=0\;\;\;\text{on }(0,T)\times\{-R,R\}.\tag2$$ Now let $\alpha\in(1,p)$.

> **Question 1**: How can we show that $$\int_0^xu^{-\alpha}(t,r)u_r(t,r)\:{\rm d}r=\frac{u^{1-\alpha}(t,x)-u^{1-\alpha}(t,0)}{1-\alpha}\tag3$$ for all $x\in[0,R]$?

I've tried to obtain the right-hand side using partial integration, but wasn't able to simplify the resulting question in a way which yields the right-hand side. Is there something I'm missing which yields the desired equality in a different way?

---

Assume now that $$u(0,\;\cdot\;)=u_0\;\;\;\text{on }[-R,R]$$ for some $u_0:[-R,R]\to[0,\infty)$ such that $u_0\not\equiv0$, $u_0$ is nonincreasing on $[0,R]$ and satisfies $$u_0(x)=u_0(-x)\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in[-R,R]\tag4.$$

> **Question 2**: How do we see that $u^{-\alpha}(t,x)$ is actually well-defined for all $t\in[0,T)$ and $x\in[0,R)$?

We obviously need to exclude $x=R$, since $u(t,R)=0$ for all $t\in(0,T)$ by $2$. But how do we now that $u(t,x)\ne0$ for all $t\in[0,T)$ and $x\in[0,R)$?

Comment: For question 1 it's just $\partial _r ( \frac{u^{1-\alpha}}{1-\alpha}) = u^{-\alpha}u_r$.

Comment: For question 2, note that $u$ can be identically zero. So there is no reason why $u$ is nonzero.

Comment: @ArcticChar Thank you for your comments. I missed the assumption $u_0\not\equiv0$. Given that $u\equiv0$ should no longer be a possible solution and we should be able to show that for all $t\in(0,T)$, there is a $C>0$ s.t. $u_x(t,x)\le-Cx$ for all $x\in[0,R]$.

Comment: Would the equation be have $|u|^p$ instead of $u^p$? I don't see how to make sense of $u^p$ when $u$ is negative...

Answer (score 1):

As Arctic Char mentioned, even though it is partial derivatives you can think of it as similar to saying:
$$\int yy' dx=\int ydy$$
Since you know that:
$$\partial_r u^{1-\alpha}=(1-\alpha)u^{-\alpha}\partial_ru=(1-\alpha)u^{-\alpha}u_r$$
which means you can rewrite your integral as:
$$\int_0^x\partial_r\left[\frac{u^{1-\alpha}}{1-\alpha}\right]dr$$
which will give the desired result

---

One comment that you can make is that by rearranging the equation we get:
$$u=(u_t-u_{xx})^{1/p}$$
so for $u$ to be real (unless $p$ is an odd integer) we require $u_t>u_{xx}$.

One thing to note is that from the conditions you have stated we can say that $u_0'\le0\,\,\forall x\in[0,R]$ and obviously symmetrical about $x=0$ for this to be true we can say one of two things, $u_0'(x)=0$ or $u_0'(0)=0$. Think about what the behaviour of $u_0$ tells you about $u$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know an answer to question 2 as well? (Please take note that I've added the assumption $u_0\not\equiv0$.

Comment: I will add some now